# Next Step in Migrating Exchange 2003 to GMail (SPF risks when changing MX record vs disable SMTP)

Tags: exchange-2003, mx-record, spf

Our company has been struggling to migrate Exchange to GMail for last 2 years (I will leave this for /r/talesfromtechsupport). We have two domains on two different ccTLDs, and lately Exchange is just forwarding messages to GMail.

I think it is the right time to change MX records, so that GMail effectively would host both domains. However, as people are still using Exchange for Public Folder storage, once in a while they will send messages from the old domain.

I was wondering whether it can impact the message delivery? I think it has to do something with SPF, but resources are slightly dry and my competence is low.

Perhaps there is a way to disable SMTP on Exchange altogether, but in a way that users wouldn't have the option?

Thank you all for help.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Answer (score 0):

SPF typically only affects **outbound** message delivery, so based on a concern purely of incoming mail delivery and SPF then there's nothing to worry about.

And providing users are using Gmail to send messages, and your SPF records are in place (or are absent) and there are no problems, then again there's nothing to worry about.

Try using a tool like [Wormly SMTP test tool](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server) to pipe a message in manually into Gmail's SMTP server in the way you think messages will be delivered, and if that works then really there's no reason that I can think of why you shouldn't change your MX records.

Keep your existing Exchange servers in there with a lower priority (e.g. priority 20, with GMail having priority 10) just in case there's something unforseen...

Comment: "And providing users are using Gmail to send messages" - that is the thing that I am sure will not happen, therefore I want know how can I prevent them from doing so. Trying to teach them not to will be impossible and there will be no political will from upper management to do so.

Comment: So, are you going **from** Exchange or **to** it? If you're going from Exchange to Gmail, why would you not want your users to send messages from Gmail if that's where their mail is? Or have I missed something?

Comment: I do not want people sending from Exchange, which is still required for Public Folder storage.

Comment: Please describe what your users currently do to send emails. Do they log in to both Exchange and Gmail depending on which domain they want to send from? Or is your Gmail configuration set up to allow them to send from both?

Comment: 90% of them use Outlook with Gmail IMAP/SMTP server, but occasionally some of them will use Exchange, as it's been set up as default after adding Exchange account to Outlook. Messages **received to** Exchange are forwarded to their Gmail. Hope that helps.